Stabilizer of a lattice $\Gamma \subset G$ in the group of automorphisms $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is always discrete?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $G$ be a (simply) connected Lie group whose semisimple part has no compact factors, and let $\Gamma $ be a lattice (uniform?) in $G$.
Is it true that the stabilizer $\operatorname{Stab}_{\Aut(G)} (\Gamma)$ of $\Gamma$ in the group of automorphisms $\Aut(G)$ is always discrete?
In some special cases this is true (R. Mosak, M. Moskowitz. Stabilizers of Lattices in Lie Groups,  Journal of Lie Theory Volume 4 (1994) 1–16).

You have to assume that $G$ has discrete center, otherwise the claim is clearly false. For semisimple groups the claim holds due to Zariski density of lattices.

We are talking about arbitrary Lie groups. For Abelian Lie groups, the statement I indicated is true (we are not talking about the normalizer of a lattice in a Lie group, but about the stabilizer of this lattice in an automorphism group of this Lie group!). For semisimple Lie groups, the statement I indicated is almost obvious.

Oh, I see, I misread the question.

It turned out that the statement I indicated is not true in the general case! A counterexample is the follows.
The Lie group $G$ is the universal covering for the group $E_2$ of orientation-preserving motion of a two-dimensional Euclidean plane. This Lie group is three-dimensional, solvable and has the form ${\bf R} \cdot {\bf R}^2 $. The lattice $\Gamma = {\bf Z} \cdot {\bf Z}^2$. Here the stabilizer is isomorphic to ${\bf R}^2$ and therefore non-discrete.

Ah, also $\mathbf{Z}^n$ in $\mathrm{Isom}^+(\mathbf{R}^n)=\mathbf{R}^n\rtimes\mathrm{SO}(n)$ works, for the same reason ($n\ge 2$).
